# Updating Sqlite DB on iPhone Applliction

Tags: iphone, sqlite, app-store

i'm developing an iphone app that uses local Sqlite3 DB; i would like to add an "Update data" menu voice that checks whether a new sqlite db version is found on my site and, if true, downloads file to the device. Data can change very often, so i'm asking if it is possible in some way without passing from the AppStore.
If yes, how can it be implemented?
Thanks in advance.
Grettings !
c.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a sqlite file on app launch and switch it out easily in the code.  Of course if the schema changes then thats a bigger problem but if its just data then it should be straightforward.